# Use of citation helper

Tags: support, hyperlinks, citation

**New edit**. I edited again the question following Martin Sleziak's comment below. As he correctly guessed, *the question is not about the elementary use* of the citation helper, so I found necessary to correct it. Apologies for my poor English.
**Disclaimer**. I believe this question is not a duplicate, since I have found only one pertaining to the same topic in Meta. However, if I am wrong, please tell me and I'll remove it immediately.

Recently I noticed the very useful "Citation Helper" on the toolbars of the edit sections of MathOverflow and of Mathematics.StackExchange. Does there exists a manual on how to use the tool inside a post? Precisely, I'd like very much to use cited items as tags, in a similar way as it already  happens for numbered formulas in Math Jax. For example this formula
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v})+\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla_\mathbf{x} f(t,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v})+\mathbf{F}\cdot\nabla_\mathbf{v}f(t,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v})=\mathsf{C}(f,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v})\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
is tagged and can be accessed by clicking on the hyperlink \eqref{1} whenever it is placed in the post. I would like to make items in a **Bibliography** or **References** section accessible from other part of  my Qs&As by using hyperlinks placed in the main text: is this possible and, if so, where I can find the syntaxes for doing so?

Comment: A nice explanation of how the citation helper works is in this blog post: [MathOverflow and MathSciNet](https://blogs.ams.org/beyondreviews/2016/04/17/mathoverflow-and-mathscinet/) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170319190149/https://blogs.ams.org/beyondreviews/2016/04/17/mathoverflow-and-mathscinet/)). Since then it has changed a bit - it now includes Zentralblatt link rather than MathSciNet. But that's not the substantial difference. I've seen this link in comments to this MathOverflow Meta post: [New feature - citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2583).

Comment: However, it is quite likely that you're after something else. (As you write about "reference items ... using hyperlinks".)

Comment: Thanks for the updating the post (I am not sure, but perhaps after the edit the ([meta-tag:hyperlinks] tag might be also a suitable tag for the question.) If this feature request gets implemented at some point, I think that it could be used also for the purpose you describe: [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894). (Although I don't think it is very likely to happen, considering that the post has been around since 2010.)

Comment: I think if you had support for hyperref packages you could do this with mathjax.